# How to show the selected date in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm Working with Asp .net MVC3.i'm having a text box with a datepicker image that textbox having a date filled in it.when i click select the datepicker image the popped up datepicker has to be pointing out the date which is in textbox instead of pointing the current date.Is there any jquery for this?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setDate` option :

```
$('element').datepicker({
    defaultDate: '02/02/12'
}).datepicker('setDate', '02/02/12');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2fSwE/)

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine by default.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymLe2/1/

```
$('#dated').datepicker({showOn: "button"});
```

You need to post your code, so as to be able to identify the cause of your problem.